# Using a Repo in an Ecto migration

Tags: elixir, database-migration, ecto

I've got an Ecto migration where I'd like to modify some columns but also migrate some data. For example:

```elixir
import Ecto.Query

defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.AddStatus do
  alter table(:foo) do
    add(:status, :text)
  end

  foos = from(f in MyApp.Foo, where: ...)
         |> MyApp.Repo.all

  Enum.each(foos, fn(foo) ->
    # There's then some complex logic here to work 
    # out how to set the status based on other attributes of `foo`
  end)
end
```

Now, the problem here is that by calling `MyApp.Repo.all` the migration essentially uses a separate database connection to the one which the `alter table...` statement used (**EDIT**: This assumption is false, see the accepted answer). Consequently, no `status` column so the whole migration blows up! Note, we're using a `postgres` database so DDL statements are transactional.

I *could* do this as two separate migrations or a `mix` task to set the data, leaving the migration only for the schema change, but would prefer not to in order to ensure data consistency.

Any thoughts on how to use the same database connection for `MyApp.Repo` queries in this manner?

**EDIT**: Note, I'm working on a small set of data and downtime is acceptable in my use case. See José's response below for some good advice when this is not the case.

Comment: Does adding a call to `flush()`  after `alter` work?

Comment: Yes, `flush()` works! Why does that work? Am I wrong about there being two different connections here and it's simply not run the steps yet?

Comment: Yes, `flush()` should work. The whole migration is wrapped in a transaction, which means any DDL statement as well as Repo expressions work on the same connection/transaction. The issue is that we group the ddl statements together until the end of the transaction or until a flush. @Dogbert should submit an answer. :) I will edit my answer to remove the wrong advice.

Comment: Thanks again José! If @Dogbert if you add an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: So will the `flush()` commit the transaction? What if there's some exception raised during the rest of that migration? Will the changes before the `flush()` be rollbacked too?

Comment: No, `flush()` does not commit the transaction, it just executes the statements that have been queued up before that point. Think of each statement in the migration as getting pushed into a queue, then all run once everything's been queued up. `flush()` essentially lets you execute what's already been queued before adding subsequent statements. The entire migration is wrapped in a transaction, so in the event of an exception everything (regardless of `flush()`) that had been executed would get rolled back.

Comment: For added context @ŠtefanĽupták, the way things are added to the queue is through the `Ecto.Migration` DSL functions like `alter()` or `create()`. The reason I needed a `flush()` is that in the example above I'm doing other stuff that assumes everything above had been run. So the migration was failing because I'd put stuff into the queue but not actually run it on the database when I tried to subsequently use it in the `Enum.each()`.

Comment: Thanks @seddy. I had the same problem but was afraid of having fragile migrations because of the `flush()`. Now you have cleared that up for me. 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can execute the current pending changes in a migration by calling [`Ecto.Migration.flush/0`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#flush/0). Any code after that will have the status field available.

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.AddStatus do
  alter table(:foo) do
    add(:status, :text)
  end

  flush()

  foos = from(f in MyApp.Foo, where: ...)
         |> MyApp.Repo.all

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Generally speaking, doing data migration and changing the DDL at the same time is a bad practice. If this is a live system and the migration takes long, you may generate a lot of contention for a long period of time.

If your application is still processing requests, new entries can be added while the data is processed, and those won't be processed!

There are different ways to tackle this, depending on the use case, but they usually require a step by step approach. For example, if you are adding a new column:

- the first step is to introduce the new column in the database and make sure that the new column is populated when new entries are created. This step is only to guarantee that all future entries will be correctly populated.
- then a second step is to migrate the old data
- finally, you can put the new data live as you can assume all of the entries are properly populated

Comment: Thanks José! I definitely agree with this:

> If this is a live system and the migration takes long, you may generate a lot of contention for a long period of time.

However, I should probably caveat this with I'm only looking at ~100 rows for an internal app that we have a small out-of-hours maintenance window for.

Comment: I may just do this in a second migration if there's no way to access the connection (or it's sufficiently difficult to access). We're already doing a phased approach to rollout, but the maintenance window gives us flexibilty to write slightly less code and skip a step or two is all :).

Comment: I've added an EDIT in my main question to point to this post as I think it's important, but I think Dogbert has potentially offered an alternative by calling `flush()`, which appears to work. Can you explain why that works for me please? Am I wrong about there being different connections and it's just that the `alter` statement hasn't *actually* run yet?