# Migrate data from another Repo in Ecto migration

Tags: elixir, database-migration, ecto

Similar to this question: [Using a Repo in an Ecto migration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48381568/733760), I've got an Ecto migration where I'd like create some new tables but also migrate some data from a *different* repository. For example:

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateFoo do
  use Ecto.Migration
  import Ecto.Query

  def change do
    create table(:foo) do
      add(:status, :text)
    end

    flush()
    execute &import_from_AnotherApp/0
  end

  defp import_from_AnotherApp()
    foos = from(f in AnotherApp.Foo, where: ...)
           |> AnotherApp.Repo.all

    Enum.each(foos, fn(foo) ->
      # Insert data from AnotherApp into MyApp foo table
    end)

  end
end
```

The problem is when running mix ecto.migrate I get

```elixir
** (RuntimeError) could not lookup Ecto repo AnotherApp.Repo because it was not started or it does not exist
```

I tried adding `AnotherApp` as a dependency of `MyApp` in `mix.exs` but I still get the same error.

Can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried manually starting `AnotherApp.Repo` before execusing a query? The ecto migration mix task isn't starting your full application.

Comment: @joshnuss yes. I did like in Everett's answer and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run mix tasks, they run in their own processes, so other applications (including the main application housing the task) may not be started.

Sometimes you have to put lines like these into your custom mix tasks and I suspect you could put them into your migrations:

```
{:ok, _} = Application.ensure_all_started(:my_app)
{:ok, _} = Application.ensure_all_started(:another_app)
```

However, sometimes ensuring that they have started isn't enough: sometimes you have to explicitly start the process. In your case, you'd have to start up the other app's `Ecto.Repo`.  Usually, you [start your Ecto repos](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.html) by listing them in your app's supervisor inside `application.ex`, e.g.

```
def start(_type, _args) do
  children = [
    {MyApp.Repo, []},
    {AnotherApp.Repo, []},
  ]

  opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyApp.Supervisor]
  Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
end
```

But if that other app doesn't need to be started for your app's regular functionality, then you can start the process manually by running `MyApp.Repo.start_link([])`. -- you could put that into your migration to see if it comes up:

```
x = MyApp.Repo.start_link([])
IO.inspect(x)
```

With luck, you'll get an `:ok` and a process id, but if not, you should get some useful debugging info.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `with_repo(repo, fun, opts \\ [])` should do it for you
https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migrator.html#with_repo/3